# What would be the alignment of a Slaanesh worshipper?

Tags: warhammer-40k, warhammer-fantasy, dungeons-and-dragons

Would a Slaanesh worshipper necessarily have an evil alignment in D&D? can't a character be a hedonistic Slaanesh worshipper without mutating and going insane, if so, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although this is probably more adept for rpg stack, I'll answer.

Slaanesh is not only a god whose worshippers are hedonistic. They are totally insane, crazy and chaotic. This limitates your alignments to the "Chaotic" branch.

Also, they enjoy and find pleasure in pain, getting it and causing it to others, this also limitates de "Good" branch of the alignment. A Chaotic Good character couldn't enjoy causing damage or pain to others.

So, from my point of view, a Slaanesh worshipper must be Chaotic Neutral or Chaotic Evil. No other alignment in the collection fits into their primary behaviour.

Comment: Forgive me for not wording my question properly, I'm more interested in discussing Warhammer lore vs D&D lore than systems, for example, worshipping a god in D&D does not technically affect you mentally, you worship, and perhaps at some point your god may want to favor you if you ask for help, but in the case of gods of chaos in Warhammer it seems to be that if you worship them, for example if a relatively normal person drinks, has sex etc in excessive amounts he would be worshipping Slaanesh and their minds would be warped automatically, why is this?

Comment: Warhammer lore presents a very polarized spectre of beliefs. While you can find usually that type of spectre also in D&D worlds, it usually depicts also "grayer" shades of faith. So you can find people from a wider alignment arcs worshipping gods. You won't expect to find evil characters worshipping Torm or Tyr (from forgottern realms setting), but with less "strict" deities you can find quite curious alignment combinations. However, in Warhammer, things are just black or white, there is no room to good lawful people worshipping chaos, because their same nature is to twist weak enough souls.

Comment: So what I'm getting here is that while having a "moderate" Slaanesh supporter (not sadistic, not insane, just hedonistic) would be possible, there just aren't any in canon because the writers wanted to polarize the setting? or would that character eventually get corrupted because of some passive magical influence?

Comment: In warhammer, the chaos influence is something that affects souls. Long before any mortal knows or gets insight into the chaos, it's soul is twisted far beyond reparation. We've seen this hundreds of times in the novels. The fact is, you could have a good person with an hedonistic nature, but if he delves deep enough into this to "find" Slaanesh, surely his soul is already condemned. He won't change from an alignment to another in the blink of an eye. But he'll be making steps further into madness each passing day, changing his behaviour to a more extreme version and eventually becoming mad

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, that last explanation gave me all the answers I sought, again, thank you.